# Project imported from Eclipse to Android Studio. APK files and some other files in bin folder are not updating anymore

Tags: android, build, apk, android-studio

I recently imported a android project from Eclipse to Android Studio. Now whenever I run the project or build the project, in the bin folder files are not updating properly. Specially the apk file and some other files(AndroidManifest.xml, classes.dex, res and aidl folder) are not updating anymore. I could not find out anything like clean project in Android Studio. Please help how can I solve this issue.

Comment: I tried to delete bin folder in a test project, the try rebuild. It doesn't create a new bin folder!

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there's a way to get a clean build via the UI (I haven't found it yet, anyway), but it's pretty easy via commandline.  From the root directory of your project:

```
./gradlew clean
```